# Daily Value of Stock Portfolio Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query, window-functions

I am working on making a database that queries the daily balance of a stock portfolio. The balance would be calculated as (sharesA x priceA)+(sharesB x priceB), etc. for each day.

I have a pricesclose table like below:

```
date       | ticker | close
2020-01-02 | IVV    | 326.32
2020-01-03 | IVV    | 323.81
2020-01-06 | IVV    | 325.09
2020-01-07 | IVV    | 324.20
2020-01-02 | IEF    | 110.73
2020-01-03 | IEF    | 111.47
2020-01-06 | IEF    | 111.35
2020-01-07 | IEF    | 111.19
```

And a transactions table:

```
id | ticker | transaction_type | shares | price  | transaction_date
1  | IVV    | buy              | 18     | 324.98 | 2020-01-02
2  | IEF    | buy              | 36     | 110.69 | 2020-01-02
3  | IEF    | sell             | -6     | 111.35 | 2020-01-06
```

What I want is:

```
date       | ticker | shares | close  | totalshares | marketvalue 
2020-01-02 | IEF    | 36     | 110.73 |          36 | 3986.28
2020-01-02 | IVV    | 18     | 326.32 |          18 | 5873.76
2020-01-03 | IEF    |        | 111.47 |          36 | 4012.92
2020-01-03 | IVV    |        | 323.81 |          18 | 5828.58
2020-01-06 | IEF    | -6     | 111.35 |          30 | 3340.5
2020-01-06 | IVV    |        | 325.09 |          18 | 5851.62
2020-01-07 | IEF    |        | 111.19 |          30 | 3335.7
2020-01-07 | IVV    |        | 324.2  |          18 | 5835.6
2020-01-08 | IEF    |        | 110.93 |          30 | 3327.9
2020-01-08 | IVV    |        | 325.85 |          18 | 5865.3
```

But this is what I'm getting:
[image: query result]

Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
  pricesclose.Date
 ,pricesclose.ticker
 ,transactions.shares
 ,pricesclose.close
 ,(pricesclose.close * transactions.shares) AS mktvalue, 
 ,SUM(shares) OVER(partition by pricesclose.ticker order by pricesclose.date)
FROM 
  pricesclose
LEFT JOIN 
  transactions
    ON pricesclose.ticker = transactions.ticker
        AND pricesclose.Date = transactions.transDate
ORDER BY
  pricesclose.Date
```

For some reason, the `SUM OVER` isn't totaling each ticker properly. My other issues is getting the `mktvalue` column to reference the sum column. I am also unsure of the best way to have the total balance in one line instead of six like it's currently doing.

Please let me know what is wrong with my `SUM OVER`. Or if there is a better way to execute this, I am open to that as well.

Comment: Do you need the `SUM` of each ticker per day?  That would be `PARTITION BY pricesclose.ticker, pricesclose.date`

Comment: Close. I am needing the sum of all transactions up to a certain date. For instance, IEF should show 36 shares on dates 2020-01-02 and 2020-01-03; then on 2020-01-06, because 6 shares were sold, there should be 30 shares on 2020-01-06, and 2020-01-07.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you would want the output to look like?

Comment: I added an excel screenshot of the desired output. I'm needing the sum column to say "sum all transaction shares of ticker 'x' that is <= row date. Here is a fiddle of what I have so far http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9e4ff/3

Comment: Ok, think I see it now - I'll try and give you some guidance tomorrow when I have some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - just needed to multiply the closing price by the running total of shares:

```
SELECT 
  pricesclose.Date
 ,pricesclose.ticker
 ,transactions.shares
 ,pricesclose.close
 ,SUM(transactions.shares) OVER (PARTITION BY pricesclose.ticker ORDER BY pricesclose.date) AS totalshares
 ,pricesclose.close * SUM(transactions.shares) OVER (PARTITION BY pricesclose.ticker ORDER BY pricesclose.date) AS marketvalue
FROM 
  pricesclose
LEFT JOIN 
  transactions
    ON pricesclose.ticker = transactions.ticker
        AND pricesclose.date = transactions.transaction_date
ORDER BY 
  pricesclose.date
 ,pricesclose.ticker
```

Output:

```
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|         date         | ticker | shares | close  | totalshares | marketvalue |
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z | IEF    | 36     | 110.73 |          36 | 3986.28     |
| 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z | IVV    | 18     | 326.32 |          18 | 5873.76     |
| 2020-01-03T00:00:00Z | IEF    | (null) | 111.47 |          36 | 4012.92     |
| 2020-01-03T00:00:00Z | IVV    | (null) | 323.81 |          18 | 5828.58     |
| 2020-01-06T00:00:00Z | IEF    | -6     | 111.35 |          30 | 3340.5      |
| 2020-01-06T00:00:00Z | IVV    | (null) | 325.09 |          18 | 5851.62     |
| 2020-01-07T00:00:00Z | IEF    | (null) | 111.19 |          30 | 3335.7      |
| 2020-01-07T00:00:00Z | IVV    | (null) | 324.2  |          18 | 5835.6      |
| 2020-01-08T00:00:00Z | IEF    | (null) | 110.93 |          30 | 3327.9      |
| 2020-01-08T00:00:00Z | IVV    | (null) | 325.85 |          18 | 5865.3      |
+----------------------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```