# POSTGRES: Calculate Portfolio values for each day

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a query to calculate the daily value of a portfolio of stocks.

I have a `transactions` table:

```
id | portfolio_id  | stock | transaction_type | shares | price  | transaction_date
1  | PA1           | APPL  | buy_sell         | 18     | 324.98 | 2020-01-02
2  | PA1           | MSF   | buy_sell         | 36     | 110.69 | 2020-01-03
3  | PA1           | MSF   | buy_sell         | -6     | 111.35 | 2020-01-06
4  | PA1           | APPL  | buy_sell         | -18    | 324.96 | 2020-01-10
```

I have a `stock_histories` table:

```
id   | value  | value_date
APPL | 324.98 | 2020-01-01
APPL | 321.55 | 2020-01-02
APPL | 320.38 | 2020-01-03
APPL | 327.13 | 2020-01-04
APPL | 334.56 | 2020-01-05
APPL | 364.78 | 2020-01-06
APPL | 360.95 | 2020-01-07
APPL | 344.58 | 2020-01-08
APPL | 340.38 | 2020-01-09
APPL | 339.55 | 2020-01-10
APPL | 339.55 | 2020-01-11
APPL | 334.55 | 2020-01-12
MSF  | 110.69 | 2020-01-01
MSF  | 110.69 | 2020-01-02
MSF  | 111.35 | 2020-01-03
MSF  | 113.22 | 2020-01-04
MSF  | 111.15 | 2020-01-05
MSF  | 110.25 | 2020-01-06
MSF  | 112.23 | 2020-01-07
MSF  | 123.45 | 2020-01-08
MSF  | 118.66 | 2020-01-09
MSF  | 121.10 | 2020-01-10
MSF  | 121.11 | 2020-01-11
MSF  | 131.90 | 2020-01-12
...other daily values....
```

I want this result:

```
date       | ticker | shares | price  | totalshares | marketvalue 
2020-01-02 | APPL   | 18     | 324.98 |          18 | 5849.64
2020-01-03 | APPL   |        | 320.38 |          18 | 5766.84
2020-01-04 | APPL   |        | 327.13 |          18 | 5888.34
2020-01-05 | APPL   |        | 334.56 |          18 | 6022.08
2020-01-06 | APPL   |        | 364.78 |          18 | 6566.04
2020-01-07 | APPL   |        | 360.95 |          18 | 6497.1
2020-01-08 | APPL   |        | 344.58 |          18 | 6202.44
2020-01-09 | APPL   |        | 340.38 |          18 | 6126.84
2020-01-10 | APPL   |        | 339.55 |          0  | 0
2020-01-03 | MSF    |        | 110.69 |          36 | 3984.84
2020-01-04 | MSF    |        | 113.22 |          36 | 4075.92
2020-01-05 | MSF    |        | 111.15 |          36 | 4001.4
2020-01-06 | MSF    |        | 110.25 |          30 | 3307.5
2020-01-07 | MSF    |        | 112.23 |          30 | 3366.9
2020-01-08 | MSF    |        | 123.45 |          30 | 3703.5
2020-01-09 | MSF    |        | 118.66 |          30 | 3559.8
2020-01-10 | MSF    |        | 121.10 |          30 | 3633
2020-01-11 | MSF    |        | 121.11 |          30 | 3633.3
2020-01-12 | MSF    |        | 131.90 |          30 | 3957
```

Is really similar to the issue describe here: [Daily Value of Stock Portfolio Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271442/daily-value-of-stock-portfolio-postgres)

But I am stuck with the window function (in a performance way) to only get the result start with the first `transactions` date until to start with the first `stock_histories` date of the stock, same when the stock goes to 0.

Thanks, guys for your help!

EDIT: I created a db-fiddle, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g8Utp5kWuVxPSusj2eZaMb/0

The version of Postgres, I using is 13

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You could at least provide a fiddle for your table structures and data (dbfiddle.uk) - also, your version of PostgreSQL would be handy! Help us to help you! À+!

Comment: sure i can do it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

Data preparation.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  "id" INT not null, 
  "portfolio_id" varchar(255) not null,
  "stock" varchar(255) not null,
  "transaction_type" varchar(55) not null,
  "shares" decimal(20, 9) not null,
  "price" decimal(20, 9) not null,
  "transaction_date" date not null);


CREATE TABLE stock_histories (
  "id" varchar(255) not null, 
  "value" decimal(20, 9) not null,
  "value_date" date not null);


INSERT INTO transactions (id, portfolio_id, stock, transaction_type, shares, price, transaction_date) VALUES 
(1, 'PA', 'APPL', 'buy_sell', 18, 324.98, '2020-01-02'),
(2, 'PA', 'MSF', 'buy_sell', 36, 110.69, '2020-01-03'),
(3, 'PA', 'MSF', 'buy_sell', -6, 111.35, '2020-01-06'),
(4, 'PA', 'APPL', 'buy_sell', -18, 324.96, '2020-01-10');


INSERT INTO stock_histories (id, value, value_date) VALUES 
('APPL', 324.98, '2020-01-01'),
('APPL', 321.55, '2020-01-02'),
('APPL', 320.38 , '2020-01-03'),
('APPL', 327.13, '2020-01-04'),
('APPL', 334.56, '2020-01-05'),
('APPL', 364.78, '2020-01-06'),
('APPL', 360.95, '2020-01-07'),
('APPL', 344.58, '2020-01-08'),
('APPL', 340.38, '2020-01-09'),
('APPL', 339.55, '2020-01-10'),
('APPL', 339.55, '2020-01-11'),
('APPL', 334.55, '2020-01-12'),
('MSF', 110.69, '2020-01-01'),
('MSF', 110.69, '2020-01-02'),
('MSF', 111.35, '2020-01-03'),
('MSF', 113.22, '2020-01-04'),
('MSF', 111.15, '2020-01-05'),
('MSF', 110.25, '2020-01-06'),
('MSF', 112.23, '2020-01-07'),
('MSF', 123.45, '2020-01-08'),
('MSF', 118.66, '2020-01-09'),
('MSF', 121.10, '2020-01-10'),
('MSF', 121.11, '2020-01-11'),
('MSF', 131.90, '2020-01-12');
```

Below sql should do the trick.

```
select *
from
(
  with transactions as
(select 
      t.*
,   coalesce(LAG(shares,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY stock
        ORDER BY transaction_date
    ),0) previous_share
    ,case when coalesce(LAG(stock,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY stock
        ORDER BY transaction_date
    ),'') =stock then coalesce(LAG(shares,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY stock
        ORDER BY transaction_date
    ),0)+shares else shares end as total_current_share
      ,
    coalesce(lead(transaction_date,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY stock
        ORDER BY transaction_date
    ),now()) end_date  
      from transactions t
      where 1=1 
             order by t.stock,t.transaction_date
     )
select 
sh.value_date,t.stock,t.total_current_share,sh.value,sh.value*t.total_current_share market_value
,to_Char(t.transaction_Date,'dd.mm.yyyy') transaction_Date
,to_Char(t.end_Date,'dd.mm.yyyy') end_Date
,to_Char(sh.value_date,'dd.mm.yyyy') value_date 
, coalesce(lag(total_current_share,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY stock
        ORDER BY transaction_date
    ),1) before_share 
from transactions t
inner join stock_histories sh on sh.id=t.stock 
and t.transaction_Date<=sh.value_Date
      and t.end_date>sh.value_Date
order by t.stock,t.transaction_Date,sh.value_Date 
) final
  where 1=1
 and before_share!=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But the transaction CTE look have an issue. The previous share takes the value of the column shares coming from the previous row.

I tried to deal by changing the LAG value of using `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` without success...

Do you think it's possible to achieve that with out a `UNION ALL` ?

Comment: This query look make the job:


```
     SUM(coalesce(gross_share, 0)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY stock_id
        ORDER BY transaction_date      
      ) AS total_current_share,
```

Any feedback, are welcome

Comment: If I understand you correctly your are having problems when changing stocks. I edited the query. Also check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d09b6268c9072a426c089ef45db3c96c